# Partially filled object appears completely null at controller after ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send a partially filled object to my controller through an Ajax post.

```
var child =
{
    Property1: 1,
    Property2: 'test',
};
$.ajax({
    url: '/MyController/AddNewTest',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"MyObject": child},
    success: function (data) {
    //Do stuff
    },
    error: function (data) {
    //Do stuff
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddNewTest(MyObject object)
{
//Do stuff
}
```

Object:

The object `MyObject`, has a lot of other properties, but in this case, I only need `Property1` and `Property2`(I suspect that this may be the issue). Instead of sending two strings to my controller, I would prefer to pass this partially filled object, as this makes my life a bit easier down the road.

The problem is, that once the object arrives at my controller, everything inside the object is empty.

Comment: Please edit the question and include MyObject class and controller code.

Comment: It doesn't matter - Everything is spelled correctly and the properties in the object are public. I already checked that multiple times.

Comment: I assume you have `HttpPost` data annotation on your controller action?

Comment: Yea its there :-(

Comment: are there any other non nullable properties in your MyObject class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below in the $.ajax

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

due to missing the **contentType** it default takes

```
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
```

So when you receive in controller everything inside the object is empty.

Refer: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Or Else Pass data as

```
$("#btnsubmit").click(function (e) {   
        //Serialize the form datas.   
        var valdata = $("#friendform").serialize();   
        //to get alert popup   
        alert(valdata);   
        $.ajax({   
            url: "/Friend/AddFriend",   
            type: "POST",   
            dataType: 'json',   
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',   
            data: valdata   
        });   
    });
```

for this refer: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-jquery-ajax-form-submit-using-serialize-form-data-into-a-model/

Hope, you understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
        url: '/MyController/AddNewTest',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(child),
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.